# Python using argparse with cmd

Tags: python, argparse, python-cmd

Is there a way to use the `argparse` module hooked in as the interpreter for every prompt in an interface inheriting from `cmd`?

I'd like for my cmd interface to interpret the typical `line` parameter in the same way one would interpret the options and arguments passed in at runtime on the bash shell, using optional arguments with `-` as well as positional arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one way to do that is to override `cmd`'s `default` method and use it to parse the line with `argparse`, because all commands without `do_` method in your cmd.Cmd subclass will fall through to use the `default` method. Note the additional `_` before `do_test` to avoid it being used as `cmd`'s command.

```
import argparse
import cmd
import shlex

class TestCLI(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        subparsers = self.parser.add_subparsers()
        test_parser = subparsers.add_parser("test")
        test_parser.add_argument("--foo", default="Hello")
        test_parser.add_argument("--bar", default="World")
        test_parser.set_defaults(func=self._do_test)

    def _do_test(self, args):
        print args.foo, args.bar

    def default(self, line):
        args = self.parser.parse_args(shlex.split(line))
        if hasattr(args, 'func'):
            args.func(args)
        else:
            cmd.Cmd.default(self, line)

test = TestCLI()
test.cmdloop()
```

`argparse` does a `sys.exit` if it encounters unknown commands, so you would need to override or monkey patch your `ArgumentParser`'s `error` method to raise an exception instead of exiting and handle that in the `default` method, in order to stay in `cmd`'s command loop.

I would suggest you look into [cliff](http://cliff.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) which allows you to write commands that can automatically be used both as `argparse` and `cmd` commands, which is pretty neat. It also supports loading commands from `setuptools` entry points, which allows you to distribute commands as plugins to your app. Note however, that `cliff` uses [`cmd2`](http://pythonhosted.org/cmd2/), which is `cmd`'s more powerful cousin, but you can replace it `cmd` as `cmd2` was developed as a drop-in replacement for `cmd`.

Comment: sys.exit() raises SystemExit (as demonstrated in @Ramon's answer) so no monkeypatching or override needed. Just catch it and handle if you can, or re-raise.

Answer (score 4):

The straight forward way would be to create an `argparse` parser, and parse `line.split()` within your function, `expect`ing `SystemExit` in case invalid arguments are supplied (`parse_args()` calls `sys.exit()` when it finds invalid arguments).

```
class TestInterface(cmd.Cmd):

    __test1_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="test1")
    __test1_parser.add_argument('--bar', help="bar help")

    def help_test1(self): self.__test1_parser.print_help()

    def do_test1(self, line):
        try:
            parsed = self.__test1_parser.parse_args(line.split())
        except SystemExit:
            return
        print("Test1...")
        print(parsed)
```

If invalid arguments are passed, `parse_args()` will print errors, and the program will return to the interface without exiting.

```
(Cmd) test1 --unk
usage: test1 [-h] [--bar BAR]
test1: error: unrecognized arguments: --unk
(Cmd)
```

Everything else should work the same as a regular `argparse` use case, also maintaining all of `cmd`'s functionality (help messages, function listing, etc.)

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/argparse-users/7QRPlG97cak

---

Another way, which simplifies the setup above, is using the decorator below:

```
class ArgparseCmdWrapper:
    def __init__(self, parser):
        """Init decorator with an argparse parser to be used in parsing cmd-line options"""
        self.parser = parser
        self.help_msg = ""

    def __call__(self, f):
        """Decorate 'f' to parse 'line' and pass options to decorated function"""
        if not self.parser:  # If no parser was passed to the decorator, get it from 'f'
            self.parser = f(None, None, None, True)

        def wrapped_f(*args):
            line = args[1].split()
            try:
                parsed = self.parser.parse_args(line)
            except SystemExit:
                return
            f(*args, parsed=parsed)

        wrapped_f.__doc__ = self.__get_help(self.parser)
        return wrapped_f

    @staticmethod
    def __get_help(parser):
        """Get and return help message from 'parser.print_help()'"""
        f = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=2048)
        parser.print_help(file=f)
        f.seek(0)
        return f.read().rstrip()
```

It makes defining additional commands simpler, where they take an extra `parsed` parameter that contains the result of a successful `parse_args()`. If there are any invalid arguments the function is never entered, everything being handled by the decorator.

```
__test2_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="test2")
__test2_parser.add_argument('--foo', help="foo help")

@WrapperCmdLineArgParser(parser=__test2_parser)
def do_test2(self, line, parsed):
    print("Test2...")
    print(parsed)
```

Everything works as the original example, including `argparse` generated help messages - without the need to define a `help_command()` function.

Source: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134333/using-argparse-module-within-cmd-interface